# Getting Resource Id from dialog Item

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I put a picture control to a dialog, and did this settings
Misc->Type->Bitmap
Misc->Image->999

now in the OnInitDialog function of the dialog, I catched CWnd* of the picture control and I want to obtain a handle to either image I assign to the controller or image's id (which is 999)
How can I do this ?

thank you for your help.

CONTROL 65443, IDC_TRUSS_CTRL, "Static", SS_BITMAP, 13, 13, 517, 212

to be more precise about the problem, I want the number 65443 I've got the dialog's handle which holds this control and I also got the handle of the IDC_TRUSS_CTRL

what I do is:
bool error;
dialogWnd->GetDlgItemInt(controlWnd->GetDlgCtrlID(), &error, 0);

however error is 0 which means it encounter an error :\

Comment: Please use more capitals and punctuation marks. That would make your question more readable.

Comment: What picture control do you use? `CPictureHolder`?

Comment: from the tool box, I drag and drop a picture control, in properties window it say : IPictEditor

Comment: As I told you I don't think you will be able to get bitmap ID from the control. But if you explain what do you want to do maybe we can help you to find a workaround. After all, the image id you're setting in resources is hardcode so you already know it (65443).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a CBitmap pointer from the control casting to a CStatic instead of CWnd:

```
CStatic *pPictureCtrl = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem( PICTURE_CONTROL_ID ); //Notice is the control resources ID not the Image resources ID
CBitmap *pBitmap = pPictureCtrl->GetBitmap();
```

But this won't be of much help depending on what you want to do with it (?).

Comment: I do this the way you told, but GetBitmap returns null however I set the image id from the editor, can I get it ? then I'll load it manually

Comment: Actually now the question is, I have Cstatic of a picture control, an image id is assigned to the picture control via Misc:Image property and now in the OnInitDialog function can I obtain this number from CStatic ?

Comment: Sorry...I was talking by heart...try this instead of just GetBitmap:  CBitmap *pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(pPictureCtrl->GetBitmap());

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get the image id from the control. But I never tried myself.

Comment: BTW, what do you want to do with the image??

Comment: I didn't load a regular BITMAP image, instead I used a PNG and by default pngs aren't loaded. I have to load them by CPngImage class, so I iterate trough all childWindows of the dialog and if the classname is "static" I try to GetBitmap, it works well for BITMAPS but pngs aren't loaded so controller returns null at this point I intended to load them manually. However I couldn't find a way to obtain image id :(

Comment: by the way, instead of automatically loading each png to its controller, I can load them like this; CStatic xpng;
xpng.SubclassDialogItem(IDC_PNG1, hwnd);
CPngImage png(resourceID);
xpng.attach(png.Deattach());

However there is IDC_PNG1 .... IDC_PNG999 controls and it is better to do this automatically :)

Comment: But if you have the IDC_PNGXX id associated with every CStatic(or picture) control then you have already do it manually using resources editor (or anyway editing the resources with the text editor). It's better to do it by "hand" using source code than using resources editor.